# BASH script syntax check, track execution?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

As a (Debian) Linux newbie I was wondering if there is a way to track the execution of a bash shell (.sh) script ? Like in Windows you trigger that with a `echo on` command in a batch file.

My first 'unix' script ever, but I'm wondering if it will run as expected :

```
#!/bin/bash  
# switch maintenance mode off and go live with your ownCloud  
occpath='/var/www/owncloud'  
htuser='www-data'  
alias occ-do=sudo -u $htuser php $occpath/occ  
echo info: Switching to live-mode ..  
occ-do maintenance:mode --on`
```

the line I'm trying to create is like `sudo -u www-data php /var/www/owncloud/occ` (occ is what should be executed, let's assume I don't need a path for the `php` part).

Will this work; any mistakes in the syntax? And let's not forget my question about the execution following ..

Comment: Hmm, not entirely happy with the way my script is shown but I guess it's clear, right?

Comment: I fixed it to use code markdown. [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there is a way to track the execution of a bash shell (.sh) script?

You can use `set -x`, `set +x` and `set -v` as described below.

- `set -x` : Display commands and their arguments as they are executed.
- `set +x` : Turn off debugging
- `set -v` : Display shell input lines as they are read.

---

#### HowTo: Debug a Shell Script Under Linux or UNIX

> **1. Use `-x` option to debug a shell script**
>
> Run a shell script with -x option.
>
> ```
> $ bash -x script-name
> $ bash -x domains.sh
> ```
>
> **2. Use of `set` builtin command**
>
> Bash shell offers debugging options which can be turn on or off using
>   set command.
>
> - set -x : Display commands and their arguments as they are executed.
> - set -v : Display shell input lines as they are read.
>
> You can use above two commands in shell script itself:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> clear
> # turn on debug mode
> set -x
> for f in *
> do
>    file $f
> done
> # turn OFF debug mode
> set +x
> ls
> # more commands
> ```
>
> You can replace the standard Shebang line:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> ```
>
> with the following (for debugging) code:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash -xv
> ```

Source [HowTo: Debug a Shell Script Under Linux or UNIX](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/debugging-shell-script.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) -  An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.
- [set](http://ss64.com/bash/set.html) - Manipulate shell variables and functions.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
set -x
```

at the point where you want debug info start to showand

```
set +x
```

where you want it off. I don't promise what you see will always be straightforward but you can get used to id after a while.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way to check the syntax of your shell scripts :

> https://www.shellcheck.net/

Here in this website, the online syntax checker marks the line & displays the error which is caused due to incorrect syntax

As per the suggestion from other answers, you can try `set -x` & `set +x` to enable & disable debug mode respectively for tracking the execution of script.